# Perl "null" equivalent?

Tags: perl, undefined

Confused by Perl's empty string, undefined, blank, et al (or of course NULL as it's known in some other languages).

Just parsing a CSV file and for one field, if it's blank, I need to put in 0000-00-00 (it's a date field). If it's left blank/null, another program that uses the .CSV file crashes with "Incorrect date value: '' for column 'updateTranDate'"

Would something like this work?

```
if(!$fields[23])
    {
    $_ = 0000-00-00 for @fields[23];
    }
```

Comment: `if($field[23] eq ""){}`

Comment: There's a difference between an empty string and a null or undefined value. This is true for many languages, not just Perl: JavaScript, C, SQL, just to name a few off the top of my head. What might be confusing you is that in Perl, both `undef` and the empty string are falsey.

Comment: `0000-00-00`  is simply an arithmetic expression: zero minus zero minus zero

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot - if this field would be considered null for the other programs using it, then would my code above work for what I need?  Also, does 0000-00-00 need to be in single quotes or double quotes?

Comment: It depends on what the other programs expect. In general, you only need to quote fields in a CSV if they contain the delimiter, but some programs expect every single field to be quoted. Double quotes are standard, but the parsing program might expect something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is

```
if(!length $fields[23])
    {
    $fields[23] = '0000-00-00';
    }
```

This condition will be true if `$fields[23]` is either `undef` or the empty string (which are not quite the same thing).  You also need to put quotes around the date, or it will be treated as a math expression (`0 - 0 - 0` which equals `0`).

Comment: Thanks!  My original post (with quotes added) also worked, but I like your idea of covering the bases.

Comment: Why the additional `length` call? I would just use `if (! $fields[23])`. The only difference is that also returns true for a zero value. Unless zero is supposed to be interpreted as something other than '0000-00-00', say zero unix epoch ('1970-01-01'), it would work fine and be simpler.

Comment: @Mort, it depends on how you want to treat 0.  The OP specifically mentioned blank/null.  Maybe integers have a different meaning (e.g. N days ago) and should be left alone.